# Can I configure the frequency range of getByteFrequencyData()?

Tags: javascript, frequency, web-audio-api

I am using the JavaScript Web Audio API to create a frequency viewer.
Apparently the `getByteFrequencyData` distributes the gain of frequencies from 0 to 255 in an array, but the frequencies are apparently from 20Hz to 20kHz and I would like to know if I can regulate the frequency range that is stored. For example, instead of 20Hz to 20kHz, I would like 20Hz to 800Hz.
Edit:

Apparently, fftSize causes the frequency range to decrease, but increasing it a lot, leaves the analysis with a lot of delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't really configure the range.  The frequency range is always 0 to `context.sampleRate / 2`.  Changing `fftSize` just changes the number of bins that cover the range.

If you want just the range 20-800 Hz, just take the set of bins that cover this region.  You will throw away a lot of data, but there's not much that can be done.

I really think `AnalyserNode` is really meant for visualization, not analysis, despite the name.

Comment: Okay, but can i open the API and modify it to return what i want?

Comment: What do you mean "open the API"?  An alternative is to change the sample rate to 1600 Hz.  But browsers are only required to have a minimum rate of 8000 Hz.  Doing this has other problems that you might need to solve.

Comment: Open the API code and modify or do my own function based in the getByteFrequencyData analysing the range that i want. I tried to set the sample rate to 3000 (the minimum), but my analysis still slow.

Comment: To do that, you'd have to modify the C++ code of the browser and rebuild it.  You need a pretty powerful machine and lots of memory to do this.  And it will only work for you and no one else.  And what do you mean by slow?  One more alternative:  go grab some common Javascript FFT library and build your own analyser using a ScriptProcessorNode or AudioWorklet.

Comment: I will try your second solution. When i say "slow", is about the delay of the analysis. The delay between each analysis become bigger, inversely proportional to the sampling rate.